# CSS Hover: Bold changing element size with padding

Tags: html, css

Alright, of course I understand why this is happening, I'm just hoping there's some creative solution.  Let's say I have this element:

```
.element {
    padding:0 1px;
}
.element:hover {
    font-weight:bold;
}
```

It's crucial that the padding be in place for visual consistency, but is there some magical way I'm not aware of to lock the element's width down before engaging in the hover behavior?

No JavaScript allowed, unfortunately.

**JsFiddle:**

http://jsfiddle.net/M9V3Q/

**More Info**

The client is extremely specific about what they want on certain parts of the site, and the nav is one of them, much to my frustration. They insist on hover being black text on a dark shade of red used in their logo, and they want the buttons to be centered. Since different browsers render text differently, the only way to create a consistent look is to use padding to create the width. Unfortunately, with normal font weight the black is very difficult to read.

Comment: Can you create [jsFiddle](http://jsFiddle.net) illustrating your problem?

Comment: See https://css-tricks.com/bold-on-hover-without-the-layout-shift/ for a solution

Answer (score 1):

You can use this approach:

```
#hoverEle {
    width: 100px;
}

#hoverEle {
    display:inline-block;
    border:1px solid black;
    padding:3px;
    text-align: center;
}
#hoverEle:hover {
    font-weight:bold;
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/M9V3Q/4/

Cons is fixed width.

By the way, I think it is bad idea to focus buttons like this. More beautifull for user will be simple color change (e.g. `#ccc`) and, probably, `transition` effect. I think it is much more better.

Try this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/M9V3Q/9/

I think it is much more beautifull even in this variant :)

Comment: The client is extremely specific about what they want on certain parts of the site, and the nav is one of them, much to my frustration.  They insist on hover being black text on a dark shade of red used in their logo, and they want the buttons to be centered.  Since different browsers render text differently, the only way to create a consistent look is to use padding to create the width.  Unfortunately, with normal font weight the black is very difficult to read. :/

Comment: Should menu be flexible?

Comment: Yes, different text should be able to be put into the buttons and it should respond, if that's what you mean.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

```
.element {
    padding: 0 1px;
    border: 2px solid transparent;
}
.element:hover {
    font-weight: bold;
    border: none;
}
```

A fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/F4knz/

Comment: That doesn't do what I'm looking for, if you hover the first element it still changes size.

Comment: Okay. I guess I don't get what you're after. Text that goes from a normal font weight to bold will naturally take up more space. I thought you were trying to keep it from affecting adjacent elements when it does.

Comment: I am, but (at least in chrome) your solution still affects the surrounding elements.

Comment: I'm on Chrome also. The link being changed doesn't affect the adjacent link at all in my fiddle. Here's another with the links inside a list, the way you'd probably find them in a menu: http://jsfiddle.net/F4knz/1/

Comment: Hmmmmm, I wish I could say the same, that would have been a great easy solution. :(

Comment: Are you using a CSS reset for your site?

Answer (score 0):

Could always try CSS3 box-sizing. It cuts into the elements width etc for padding, border..., and so prevents the element from expanding outside its set width.

Need to prefix -moz- or -webkit- for Firefox and safari.

Comment: Could you provide a more detailed answer? Maybe by using your idea in the code.

Comment: This doesn't work, it has to be fully compatible back to IE7.